# What is this chord built on the 7th scale degree of Cmaj?

Tags: chords

What is the mystery chord? I have no idea. Thank you.

[image]

Update:

Thanks for pointing out that there are only two notes in this chord.  This is just because it is my brief outline/transcription of the progression in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXGipje16iM) song.  Please refer to the song itself to investigate further.

Comment: Hi 286642, unfortunately it seems like you want to transcribe that chord in a song rather than identify a chord based on a set of notes. This is off-topic because it is a transcription request. This info also makes the current answer outdated. Please be cautious when editing info when people have already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the notes B and D. Some of us say it isn't even a chord, but I'm not going there!

If it was a chord, it wouldn't really have a name, with only those two notes. As *part* of an existing chord in key C, it could be part of G major, part of B diminished, part of Em7, part of Dm6 for starters.So I'm thinking it's not really a chrd anyway, but a stepping stone to get from the previous C major to the F major. And any of the suggestions I made, using fuller chords, would fit in that bar with no problem.

Comment: The first chord also has only two notes, c and e. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @b3ko - not missing much, by the comment! The piece is keyed C or Am, so I assumed that that bar could be C major - which definitely needs a C note as root, and an E note to show maj/min. Is that too much to assume, given that 2/3 notes minimum makes a chord? Interesting!